# no data in elastic apm for nodejs application

Tags: node.js, elastic-stack, elastic-apm

I am trying to setup elastic apm for nodejs application. I  followed the example explained in integration page of elk.

```
var apm = require('elastic-apm-node').start({

// Override the service name from package.json
// Allowed characters: a-z, A-Z, 0-9, -, _, and space
    serviceName: 'pv-server',

// Use if APM Server requires a secret token
    secretToken: '',
    logLevel:"debug",
// Set the custom APM Server URL (default: http://localhost:8200)
    serverUrl: 'http://localhost:8200',
    captureBody: 'all',
    active: true,
    usePathAsTransactionName: true,

// Set the service environment
    environment: 'dev'
})
```

When my service starts elastic apm is showing data for CPU usages only, there is no data in transaction/traces.
I am using **express** web framework.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What web framework (express, hapi, etc.) is your service using?

Comment: @AlanStorm I am using express

Comment: I faced same problem. I solved my problem reading docs. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/nodejs/current/express.html There is mentioned very import thing _It’s important that the agent is started before you require any other modules in your Node.js application - i.e. before express, http, etc._

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. The solution was to put the APM config before the dependencies import.

ex:

```
const apm = require('elastic-apm-node').start({
    ...
})

const express = require('express');
const { Sequelize, Model, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
```